In Access query how to check if a group of records has the same value
In the following query for each group of "first", I want to check if the Values on field "Second" are true. 
For example, in the "first" field for "A" Group if the related values on the "second" field are true, the "Third" field must display "True" for both records, and if the values are false or are different the "third field value must display "False" 
I reached this approach by creating new query grouping the "First" values of the main query then I Called the related values on the main query by Dlookup where its group values are equal, but it is very slow.



First
Second
Third




A
True
True


A
True
True


B
False
False


B
Fasle
False


C
True
False


C
Fasle
False




My I ask why you're using Access in the first-place?

@Dai I've a simple Access application to automate an engineering  process, it is working for years. In addition users are very satisfy with it.

Simple things are great, yes - buuuut I recommend you port your application to SQL Server Express (yes, it’s free; and Access has an upgrade wizard built-in!) because queries like this (what you’re after) are trivial in modern SQL, but Access is forever stuck in 1992 (seriously: Access only implements a small subset of SQL-92; it’s missing-out on 30 years’ worth of improvements!)

@Dai: Why overcomplicate things? Access easily handles this simple task.

@Gustav Access doesn't support COUNT( CASE WHEN <expr> ... ) nor relational-divison, so you have to resort to using a correlated-subquery as per your posted answer - while it works, yes - it isn't ideal, as far as idealists like myself are concerned :)

@Dai you are right, I did a successful try before to migrate to MS-SQL , but the current application is for individuals to use it at work or at home.

@AshrafFouad Consider Sqlite

Use Exists in a simple query:
SELECT 
    Check.[First], 
    Check.Second, 
    Not Exists 
        (Select T.[First] From Check As T 
        Where T.[First] = Check.[First] And T.Second=False) AS Third
FROM 
    [Check];

Output (in Danish: Ja = True, Nej = False):


It is working perfectly @Gustav, thanks. but I noticed that after using a subquery the query is not updatable, is there any solution for this?

One method is to update the table itself, then call a Refresh of the displayed data.

Now is OK, I made 2 subforms, one for data entry to the table & the other is for displaying calculations using the query & both are in one main form.
